# In flink, converting from datastream to table performance implications

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

does convert from datastream to table and back from table to datastream impact performance of an app in a negative way?

Tried looking for the flink datastream to table conversion on flink documentation but couldn’t find any useful info